# Mysterious TwitterKit crash

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm seeing a rather mysterious crash while using `TwitterKit` through Fabric.

My application crashes on this line:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Twitter.self])
```

saying:

```
[Fabric] Please upgrade to the latest version of "Twitter"
[Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121)
Calling Twitter.start is not supported.
```

I integrated TwitterKit just as the docs instructed, adding keys and url schemes to my Info.plist but I can't figure out why Twitter is all the sudden crashing.

Comment: see this https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

Comment: Why the discrepancy between the two installation guides though? Can I not install Twitter via Fabric anymore?

Comment: Install twitter separately without Fabric and if you need fabric then make sure you have latest version of fabric and in Build Phases -> Run Script -> uncheck "Run script only when installing".

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Yes! I removed the integration via fabric and just went with what the twitter docs said and it worked. Looks like twitter kit doesn't work with fabric anymore

Comment: I separated Twitter instance then the error is gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**New working version with TwitterKit 3+**

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) 
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "key", consumerSecret: "secret")
```

**New Pod File**

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'TwitterKit'
```

**Old version:**

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Twitter.self])
```